# Sorbet unable to resolve constant -- even though its in the rbi

Tags: sorbet, mongoid7

Just updated mongoid.rbi from 6 to 7. Started getting a ton of errors like the following:

```
components/assets/models/assets/stats_timestamp.rb:5: Unable to resolve constant Timestamps https://srb.help/5002
     5 |    include Mongoid::Timestamps
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Looking at `sorbet/rbi/gems/mongoid.rbi` I can see the following:

```
module Mongoid::Timestamps
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Updated
end
```

(which is also in the 6.0 version)

I looked at this guidance: https://srb.help/5002

Everything is basically covered:

- the rbi is where it should be
- The rbi is regenerated to match the version in Gemfile.lock
- We're not deleting any constants
- This is not an ancestor situation

Sorbet version is `0.5.9006` however upgrading to the latest version made absolutely no changes.